# ¿Como acceder desde mi ordenador (Windows) a un contenedor Docker en una Raspberry Pi 2 por SSH?

Tags: docker, ssh

Quiero conectarme via SSH desde mi ordenador a un contenedor en concreto en mi Raspberry Pi. El contenedor ya tiene `ssh-server` y me permite conectarme a él desde la Pi pero no en cambio desde el ordenador. He usado sentencias para modificar la NAT como:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.0.10/32 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.4
```

pero sigue sin funcionar.

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Como administrador (o utilizando sudo):

```
raspi-config
```

Después en el menú que se abre te vas a la opción de 'Interfancing Options' (la quinta opción)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después vas a la opción de 'SSH' (P2):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y le das a la opción de 'Yes':
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto ya puedes acceder a tu Raspberry Pi vía ssh, permitiéndote acceder al docker.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que saber es que no te conectas al contenedor directo, si te puedes conectar al server ya lo tienes echo.
despues que te conectas por ssh al servidor. lo que te queda por hacer es escribir:

```
sudo docker attach dockerid
```

Eso si ya tienes el contenedor corriendo, si lo que quieres es conectarte a una imagen:

```
docker run -ti imagen
```

Espero haberte ayudado.